# Is it ok for REST resources to not have an id?

Tags: rest

I have (what I think as) a sub-resource. There is always only one sub resource for a given resource. Should this sub resource always have an id?
For eg. Let us say resource is employee and sub-resource is salary. Further let us also assume that you can NEVER "put" a salary. (Maybe it is always updated in the backend. Any put calls will be summarily declared as bad requests) 
In this scenario, which is a better model to read salary?

> /employees/1234/salary

or

> /employees/1234/getSalary

In the first case, salary looks like a resource.

Or is "salary" not a resource and must be thought of as a "filter" on which fields of a result should be populated?

Comment: Philosophical questions (which are primarily opinion-based) are not welcomed at Stackoverflow. At the end of the day you'll choose an answer which matches your own opinion...

Comment: yes it is ok to do this

Comment: @Brandon - I am not sure I follow - which approach are you recommending? the /salary or /getSalary??

Comment: @alfasin - in a way, a framework like REST is all philosophical. I am trying to find out what is the recommendation under this philosophy for my use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no REST Police that will come banging on your door no matter which you choose.

My opinion:

There's nothing wrong with having a subresource with no id.  As you say, what you want to do is ultimately just one way of implementing a "field filter".  It is a less flexible way of doing it.  Here are some considerations (mostly performance related):

- A client wishing to get both the Employee and Salary now has to make 2 requests
- It does not scale well to multiple properties: What if you also have another property "bonus" that needs the same treatment?  Now the client has to make 3 requests

If you are OK with those consequences then there's nothing wrong with your idea.

My opinion: use nouns for resource names, not action phrases, which means use `/salary`, not `/getSalary`.  METHOD+resource name forms your action phrase: "GET /employee/123/salary" makes sense, "GET /employee/123/getSalary" does not make sense.